# Text input with z-index inaccessible by click in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, forms

I have a borderless text input and an image input hovering above other graphics.  You can see it here: http://www.wwmlaw.dreamhosters.com/index.php

You can tab into the text input in IE6 and IE8 and it will accept input then but clicking in it does not give you a cursor.  All other browsers tested do fine.

The CSS is like so:

```
#homeSearchForm {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
}

#homeSearch {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    width:230px;
    height:20px;
    border:none;
    top:16px;
    _top:14px;
    left:676px;
    _left:730px;
    border:none;
    background:none;
    color:#FFF;
}

#homeSearchButton {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    width:55px;
    height:20px;
    border:none;
    top:17px;
    _top:15px;
    left:600px;
    _left:655px;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this question

[Input boxes with transparent background are not clickable in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098714/input-boxes-with-transparent-background-are-not-clickable-in-ie8)

I added an IE only background image:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link href="css/IE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

containing

```
background-image:url(../g/spacer.gif);
```

This resolved the issue.

JG

Answer (score 1):

Had the similar issue -> IE8 textbox was not editable (when wrapper of my App has position:absolute). Click worked only in the border. Filled with color and transparent also did not work. With this doctype change the issue is fixed.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Source: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?p=1173375#post1173375