# Z-index and IE<9, proper layering

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write simple plugin for HTML's 5 placeholder for IE 9 and below. My problem is that, although I've given my input higher z-index, the label element is still "on top" of it, therefore there's problem with focus/click.

Here's my JS code:

```
$.fn.placeholder = function () {
    return this.each( function () {
        var elem = $( this );

        if ( elem.is( "input" ) || elem.is( "textarea" ) ) {
            var placeholder = elem.attr( "placeholder" ),
                wrapper = $( "<span></span>" ).css( {"position":"relative", "display":"inline-block"} ),
                label = $( "<label></label>" ).text( placeholder ),
                border = elem.outerWidth() - elem.innerWidth(),
                paddingH = elem.innerWidth() - elem.width(),
                paddingV = elem.innerHeight() - elem.height(),
                left = elem.outerWidth( true ) - elem.width() - Math.floor( (paddingH / 2) ) - border,
                top = elem.outerHeight( true ) - elem.height() - Math.floor( (paddingV / 2) ) - border;

            label.css( {
                "position":"absolute",
                "top":top,
                "left":left,
                "color":"#a9a9a9",
                "z-index":10
            } );
            elem.css( "z-index", 1000 ).css( "position", "relative" );
            elem.wrap( wrapper );
            elem.parent().prepend( label );

            elem.focus( function () {
                elem.parent().find( "label" ).hide();
            } );
            elem.blur( function () {
                elem.parent().find( "label" ).toggle( $.trim( elem.val() ).length == 0 );
            } );
        }
    } );
};

//somewhere on document.ready
$("input").placeholder();
$("textarea").placeholder();
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Some placeholder" name="name">
    <textarea name="request" placeholder="Other placeholder"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: transparent;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
    padding: 30px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

When you try to click input/textarea under IE, there's no cursor change into "text" one, and clicking that area gives no effect, you need to click outside of label range to get focus on input.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7SXBC/2/

Comment: Can you show a live-example?

Comment: Added live example on jsfiddle, but there's bug in IE 8 on it, so I don't know if it's any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the `z-index`. If you achieve to get the `input`-element on top of the `label`, you won't be able to see the `label` at all.

Why not bind the `click`-event of the `label` to trigger the focus on the `input`/`textarea`?
It would look something like this:

```
label.click(function(e){
    elem.trigger('focus');
});
```

**UPDATE:** Your question may involve the following bug:

[Input boxes with transparent background are not clickable in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098714/input-boxes-with-transparent-background-are-not-clickable-in-ie8)

Comment: I'm able to see `label` but putting `background: transparent` for input

Comment: This's it, by creating for input/textarea `background: url(transparent-img.png);` the whole area is clickable :)